# Change Opacity of Layer based on pixel value of another layer in PremierePro/AfterEffects

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I'm trying to black out/censor segments of a screen-recording. I basically need something to check the color of a pixel on the video, and if the color does not match, it somehow censors the section of the video.

Example:
The source video needs to have at position 100;150 the color #f3f3f3. If this condition is true, just display the clip normally, if it's some other color, change the opacity to 0 or apply a blur.

(preferably in AfterEffects or PremierePro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how to change the colour of a shape in after effects based on the background colour at a given position:

Put a null on the position you wish to sample.

Put this expression in the fill colour of the object you want to change:

```
target = thisComp.layer("BGLAYER");
colorpicker = thisComp.layer("sample 1 null");
target.sampleImage(target.fromWorld(colorpicker.position), [0.5,0.5], true, time)
```

BGLAYER
is the name of your background layer (eg your video)

sample 1 null
Is the null which is colour picking

You will also need a conditional statement in the expression to switch its opacity on or off - I'm not sure how to do that, but will add it to this answer if I work it out.